# Stretch portionof SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg that represents a bar in a graph.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 8 98" preserveAspectRatio="none" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M7.5,93.541C7.5,95.727,5.933,97.5,4,97.5l0,0
    c-1.933,0-3.5-1.773-3.5-3.959V4.459C0.5,2.272,2.067,0.5,4,0.5l0,0c1.933,0,3.5,1.772,3.5,3.959V93.541z"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Is there a way to design the svg (viewbox, proportions, etc.) for it shrink to different sizes (within reason) that would protect the rounded corners and general look?  I effectively want it to slice away the middle to meet the desired size leaving a shorter but recognizable bar.  Default scaling does this:

[image]

Comment: change the values in the path with javascript so the path is longer/shorter.

Comment: appreciate that, but I was more curious if a design choice could be made with the svg that would allow simple height changes to scale in that manner. updated the question to be clear.

Comment: If you scale it by applying a transform the ends will become either thicker or thinner than the sides. You might be able to avoid that via vector-effects="non-scaling-stroke" but that's not supported on IE/Edge.

Comment: always ie...thanks, if no one comes up with a brilliant answer I'll accept that.